# How to handle negative dependent variables (differences between counts) with GLMs?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, glmm, count-data, lme4-nlme

I've been working with GLMs for a few weeks now but in the past all my dependent variables have always been positive values. Now I'm working with some negative ones (differences and changes) and have found out that the family distributions I want to use don't allow for negative values. Is there any way to get around this?

A bit more info on the situation.

My response variable is the difference in population size of all the states between 2000 and 2010. Therefore I do have negative values in my response variable as well (some states decreased in population). My parameters include, the difference in birthrates (between those two years), difference in international and domestic immigration. All data involved in this model are integers. I'm also adding the categorical parameter of "state" as a random effect. I'm using the `lme4` package's `glmer()` function to do this:

```
mod2 <- glmer((Ndifference + 74337 + 1) ~ differencebrate + DifferenceImmig +
                                          diffbdratio + (1 | state), 
              family = inverse.gaussian(link = identity))
```

Above is one of the few models I have made. In this model's case I don't get an error about non-positive values but instead get a readout that says:

```
Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
(maxstephalfit) PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance in pwrssUpdate
```

Comment: To answer this, we are going to need to know a lot more about your study, your data, your models, & your goals. Can you say more here?

Comment: @gung the response variable of the model is the difference in population size over a decade for every state. This response variable had a constant added to it to get rid of negative responses, my predictor variables include changes in domestic and international immigration to these states in the same decade (2000 and 2010) as well as the difference in birthrates (these parameters have negative response as not every state saw increases). I added a random effect of states. I am using the lme4 package with glmer.

Comment: That's a start. Can you edit that into your question statement? What model are you using, some type of count model? Can you post sample data, &/or the code you've tried? Nb, models make no distributional assumptions about x-variables; it doesn't matter if you have negative values there.

Comment: @gung I made some edits etc. I also wanted to be cautious because I thought this was a forum about statistics, not how to do things in R

Comment: That's a good point, @Lee. This isn't a forum for help w/ R code, & that isn't really what I'm suggesting. However, sometimes code can effectively illustrate how you are thinking about your model. I'm just hoping the code will help to clarify the situation.

Comment: Do you really need *differences*? Could you use the 2010 population size, & include the 2000 population size as a covariate? (I don't know too much about this, but it strikes me as Ben Bolker's wheelhouse, he may come by with some insightful comments.)

Comment: True.....I actually ended up sticking with a Gaussian distribution (basic lm models) as they actually fit the data the best.